# SQL to Identify an initial state and then check a condition to maintain the state

Tags: sql, recursion

I have a query that has me stumped, I could force brute it but there must be a more eloquent way.

We have 4 rain gauge's that provides rain measurements every minute down to 0.1mm.

[image]

The trigger point is 0.5mm of rain from any single rain gauge over the preceding 15 minutes across the most recent two hour window.  This was easy, just a sum over the preceding 14 rows works a treat.  The 'alert' is presented to a control room on an SSRS dashboard.

Now I have been asked to modify the logic so that once the trigger has been activated, it remains activated until there has been no rain recorded for at least 2 hours.  Initially I thought too easy, but then sat down and quickly realized that every time we get >=0.1 mm of rain I need to extend and inspect for another >=0.1mm until there is a 2 hour window with no rain.

To explain another way.  >=0.5 in a 15 minute will initiate the state and then any >0.1 within 2 hours of the last will recursively keep the state activated.

I am sure I am over thinking this, any help with methodology will be much appreciated (actually just typing this out has helped me think of another way to do it using lead).

Thanks in advance

Comment: (1) Please tag your question with the database you are running: oracle, sqlserver, mysql...? (2) Please show us the result you want, as tabular text. (3) What is your query so far, and which results does it produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . A state starts with 0.5 mm in a 15 minute interval.  A state ends with 2 hours of no rain.

We can calculate start and stop flags using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(site1rain1min) over (order by datetimestamp rows between 14 preceding and current row) >= 0.5
             then 1 else 0
        end) as startflag,
       (case when sum(site1rain1min) over (order by datetimestamp rows between 119 preceding and current row) = 0
             then 1 else 0
        end) as endflag
from t;
```

Then, for this, we want to identify each row whose most recent flag is a start flag.  That indicates the state.  Here is the idea:

```
select t.*,
       (case when max(case when startflag = 1 then datetimestamp end) over (order by datetimestamp) >
                  max(case when endflag = 1 then datetimestamp end) over (order by datetimestamp)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as is_reporting_period
from (select t.*,
             (case when sum(site1rain1min) over (order by datetimestamp rows between 14 preceding and current row) >= 0.5
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as startflag,
             (case when sum(site1rain1min) over (order by datetimestamp rows between 119 preceding and current row) = 0
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as endflag
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I ran it against the database and absolutely nailed it.  It is the eloquent answer, I was making it much harder than it needed to be.